# KML Google Maps - Only one placemark showing rather than multiple

Tags: maps, kml, points

I have the following Google Map located at :

http://www.ticketrich.com/uk-days-out-guide/

I am using a WP Plugin that uses shortcode to initiate the map with 
[map kml=http://www.ticketrich.com/map5.kml]

This is the contents of the kml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.google.com/earth/kml/2">
<Document>
<Folder>
<name>Folder.kml</name>
<open>1</open>
<description>
A folder is a container that can hold multiple other objects
</description>

<Placemark>
<name>Alton Towers</name>
<description>Alton Towers Information</description>
<Point>
  <coordinates>-1.891,52.9898,0</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
<name>Chessington World of Adventures</name>
<description>Chessington World of Adventures Information</description>
<Point>
  <coordinates>-0.31539,51.35013</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
<name>Banqueting House</name>
<description>Banqueting House</description>
<Point>
  <coordinates>-1.0968,53.8937</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document> 
</kml>
```

The problem is that it is only showing one of the placemarks. Whatever I've tried, I cannot get them all working. Can anyone see what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I see a bunch of placemarks on the map at http://www.ticketrich.com/uk-days-out-guide/ although it seems to be using a different KML than the one you mention.

As for http://www.ticketrich.com/map5.kml (which currently has the same code as posted in your question), it seems to be fine when viewed with google maps:  http://maps.google.com?q=http://www.ticketrich.com/map5.kml so I assume it would also work with your wordpress site.  If it still is not working can you create a page that links to this kml so we can take a look?